# How do I open the Android Mail project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-source

I have cloned the [AOSP email client](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/) and have attempted to open it in Android Studio. However, I must be doing something wrong, because I cannot build the project and all that shows up in the project tree is the following: [image: project tree]

Comment: Those apps are not designed to be built standalone, and definitely not with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages rely heavily on system packages. Hence it is difficult to get it into Android Studio. However if you are looking into an open source email client, I would recommend you look into [K9 Mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9). It's an open-source mail client.
EDIT:

You could try using this method to variable success rates:
From the AOSP root run command in a terminal:

```
make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

Then open Android Studio > Open project > Select android.ipr generated.

You will run into many dependency issues though.
Note: It might be worth giving eclipse a try. Read [this](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.in/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html).

Comment: Thank you, and I have actually already checked out K9 mail - which is why I was so confused when AOSP mail did not open just as easily! But, I believe you have answered my question. If I may ask, just how exactly are these apps designed to be developed and compiled? Surely the developers do not compile the entire OS to test the app?

Comment: Edited. And yes, you generally have to compile the entire OS. It would require a lot of porting and tremendous effect to get dependency issues away :D